# How to display the custom module on home page in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cms-pages, home-page

I have custom module by calling the controller in url address bar. How to display the custom  module in home page. Should i create block?. How to call below or above the content.

Comment: What is the link of your controller ?

Answer (score 1):

you can call your custom module's phtml file into homepage' cms page

add below code into **Content -> Pages -> home(page) -> in content section**

> {{block class="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Slideshow" template="Namespace_Modulename::bannerslider.phtml"}}

try below way if you don't have **block**

> {{ block type="core/template" template="YourtemplateFileLocation.phtml"}} //like Namespace_Modulename::bannerslider.phtml

**OR**

> {{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]::[YourTemplateFileLocation].phtml"}}

[Reference:](https://webkul.com/blog/call-phtml-file-cms-page-magento2/)

**[EDIT]**

call any phtml file into cms block

> {{block class="\\Block\" name="" template="_::/filename.phtml"}}

In your case it is look like

> {{block class="Ashore\Faq\Block\Faq\Index" name="Faq" template="Ashore_Faq::faq/index.phtml"}}

Comment: How to call the module below hotsellers on home page

Comment: if you want to display your phtml file just after hotsellers, hotsellers is existed into block just go to Content -> Blocks -> Find **Home Page Block** add above anyone method at last there you will get o/p